# How to get or set value while parsing a log file

Tags: c#, parsing, logging

Hi I am trying to get the number of files copied value from a logfile produce by a RoboCopy method within my application. The logfile is always in this format:

---

### ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows     ::     Version XP010

Started : Thu Oct 10 10:08:51 2013

Source : \ad\nas\Dev_Code\ITA\Stats\11.6.4.15\CFI\Build\
     Dest : C:\inetpub\CFI\

```
Files : *.*
```

Options : *.* /FFT /NFL /TEE /S /E /COPY:DAT /Z /IS /R:5 /W:5

---

```
                   1    \\ad\nas\Dev_Code\ITA\Stats\11.6.4.15\CFI\Build\
```

---

```
            Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
 Dirs :         1         0         1         0         0         0
**Files :         1**         1         0         0         0         0
Bytes :    1.62 m    1.62 m         0         0         0         0
Times :   0:00:03   0:00:02                       0:00:00   0:00:00

Speed :              607364 Bytes/sec.
Speed :              34.753 MegaBytes/min.

Ended : Thu Oct 10 10:08:59 2013
```

So far I am able to read the file into a streamreader but is there anything I can do to ensure I am always selecting the last instance of Files : and then the value under the Total column i.e. 1

```
try
{
// Open file for reading.
using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\LogFile.log"))
{
    // 2.
    // Read each line until EOF.
    string line;
    while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // 3.
        // Do stuff with line.
        if (line.Contains("Files"))
        {
            String content = line.ToString();
            char sep = '\t';
            string[] splitContent = content.Split(sep);
            Console.WriteLine(splitContent);
        }                        
    }
}
}
catch (Exception)
{

throw;
}
```

Output at the min = System.String[]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to select the *second* item in the array i.e.

```
Console.WriteLine(splitContent[1]);
```

Think about it, your line data looks like

```
Files :\t1\t1\t0\t0\t0\t0
```

When you call `content.Split(sep)` your array will look like

```
0: "Files :"
1: "1"
2: "1"
3: "0"
4: "0"
5: "0"
6: "0"
```

So if you map this in terms of *columns* you always want to pull the `Total` column which is at index `1` (`0` being the label column).

---

You could even use an emum here for readability e.g.

```
enum Columns
{
    Label,
    Total,
    Copied,
    Skipped,
    Mismatch,
    Failed,
    Extra
}

...
string[] rowData = content.Split('\t');
Console.WriteLine(rowData[(int)Columns.Total]);
```

Or use a `const` to avoid the cast

```
const int TotalCol = 1;

...
string[] rowData = content.Split('\t');
Console.WriteLine(rowData[TotalCol]);
```

Comment: +1 for proposing usage of a meaningful `enum` or `const int`!

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to help me - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
foreach(var section in splitContent)
{
    Console.Write("{0}\t", section);
}
Console.WriteLine();
```

Comment: I've tried adding this and now there are 2 lines outputted:                  Files : *.*
Files :         1         1         0         0         0         0
is there anything i can do to ignore the first outputted line and pull the 1st value in the 2nd line as splitting on /t does not seem to correct I am getting this error: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: @James has gave a much better answer which offers a solution to your problem

Comment: the string was split by spaces not tab delimited, thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

here's my full working example:

```
static void Main()
    {
        try
        {              
            // Open file for reading.
            using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\LogFile.log"))
            {
                // 2.
                // Read each line until EOF.
                string line;
                while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    // 3.
                    // Do stuff with line.
                    if (line.Contains("Files"))
                    {
                        if (!line.Contains("Files : *.*"))
                        {
                            String content = line.ToString();

                            string[] splitContent = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(content, @"\s+", " ").Split(' ');

                            //foreach (string s in splitContent)
                            //Console.WriteLine(s);
                            Console.WriteLine(splitContent[3]);
                        }                           
                    }                        
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```